Hosting Static Site with NGINX Proxy Manager and NGINX in Docker
Reverse Proxy Issues
My main objective is to host my own website from my homelab.
I have a domain hosted in CloudFlare, docker container NGINX Proxy Manager, and docker container NGINX serving my static website.
I have been encountering countless issues with configuring a reverse proxy to route to my NGINX site. No matter what I try or what tutorial I follow I always end up at the “Congratulations” page.
This is the docker compose for my reverse proxy:
version: '3.9'
services:
  app:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      # These ports are in format <host-port>:<container-port>
      - '4080:80' # Public HTTP Port
      - '40443:443' # Public HTTPS Port
      - '4081:81' # Admin Web Port

    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro

This is the docker compose for my NGINX server:
version: '1.0'
services:
  nginx:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 4090:80
    volumes:
      - /static-site/:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro

After launching both containers, I configure SSL with cloudflare successfully and then I build the proxy host the same way every tutorial does. I have gone through this specific process countless times so I don’t believe a typo here is my mistake.
Some notes:
Both containers are on the same network
The NGINX static website is reachable when when I type in the homelabip:port.
The admin panel for NGINX reverse proxy manager is accessible through the 4081 port I have configured as well.
Once everything is configured the 4080 port still routes to the congratulations page.

nginx have default.conf, do you use it? If i'm right, you see welcome page because your container use has default config.
There is no Nginx config in your question, for service nginx.
check your config with command docker exec -it <yournginxlatestcontainer> cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
check your files in your html folder with command docker exec -it <yournginxlatestcontainer> ls -lah /usr/share/nginx/html
if file present in this directory check static file download with curl http://<yournginxlatestcontainer>:4090/<path to static image> or via browser
To replace default configuration file, you need to transfer your nginx config or nginx config template to the container.
